# Параметры компилятора C#

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно добавить свой параметр компилятора в Visual Studio 2017? К примеру, мне нужно скомпилировать с параметром    `/out:MyAssambly.dll`.

Comment: судя по всему все настройки находятся на вкладках `Build` и `Application` в свойствах проекта.